# How do I get downloaded google fonts to work on a create-react-app bootstrapped project?

Tags: reactjs, sass, fonts

I'm having trouble setting up my project to use downloaded google fonts. I'm working with a create-react-app generated project, with Sass as my pre-processor. The project structure is seen in the linked screenshot. Both the styles and fonts folders fall directly under the parent src folder. While obviously not the same thing, I got it, with a similar structure, to work on a Vue-CLI generated project, but for whatever reason it fails with React.

I've tried changing the src url ('../../fonts/' crashes the server i.e. file not found) but nothing works. What gives?

I realize that this issue has been brought up in one way or another, but none of the suggested solutions have worked for me.

**Typography file**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  src: local('Montserrat'), url('/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Montserrat'), url('/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local('Montserrat'), url('/fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Thin.ttf') format('opentype');
}
```

**Styles (SASS) entry file**

```
@import 'utils/typography';
@import 'utils/variables';
@import 'utils/functions';
@import 'utils/mixins';

@import 'base';
```

**Screenshot of project structure**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to the `index.html`:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

replace `Lato` with any google font

then it will be available in your project for use

Comment: I could do that and it does work (as is importing the font in my scss file), but I'm trying to get the locally, downloaded fonts to work.